# cluster with contours, Android, OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, cluster-computing

I try to find contours and make five cluster with it. I have found the contours with:

```
Imgproc.findContours(bw.clone(), contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

And I would like to use the kmeans algorithm to make the five cluster. But I don't know, the step between the findContours function and the kmeans function.

```
Core.kmeans(samples32f, 5, labels, criteria, 1, Core.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

The first parameter of the kmeans function is a Mat with a float CvType and points.

How can I convert the contours to point or how must I proceed?

P.S. There are 15 contours represents 15 circle.

Comment: What do you want to cluster then? You don't just give the kmeans arbitrary length curves but fixed size feature vectors. Unless you have anything particular mind for "feature-extraction" then here's a clue: affine-invariant fourier descriptors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to cluster the pips of 5 dices.

Comment: Maybe you post a sample image on which you hand annotate the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! Thanks mainactual for your tip.

I don't understood which value the first parameter of the kmeans algorithm need.

With this [Tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html) I analyzed the problem and find out the right way.

```
    Imgproc.findContours(bw.clone(), contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Mat samples32final = new Mat(contours.size(), 2, CvType.CV_32F, new Scalar(0));

    for (int j = 0 ; j<contours.size(); j++) {
        Mat samples32f = new Mat((int) contours.get(j).size().height, 2, CvType.CV_32F, new Scalar(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) contours.get(j).size().height; i++) {
            samples32f.put(i, 0, contours.get(j).get(i, 0)[0]);
            samples32f.put(i, 1, contours.get(j).get(i, 0)[1]);
        }

        samples32f.reshape((int) contours.get(j).size().height, 2);

        Mat labels = new Mat((int) contours.get(j).size().height, 2, CvType.CV_32SC1);
        TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS + TermCriteria.MAX_ITER, 100, 1.0);
        Mat centers = new Mat();
        Core.kmeans(samples32f, 1, labels, criteria, 10, Core.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS, centers);

        samples32final.put(j,0,centers.get(0,0)[0]);
        samples32final.put(j,1,centers.get(0,1)[0]);
    }

    samples32final.reshape(contours.size(), 2);

    Mat labels = new Mat(contours.size(), 2, CvType.CV_32SC1);
    TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS + TermCriteria.MAX_ITER, 100, 1.0);
    Mat centers = new Mat();
    Core.kmeans(samples32final, 5, labels, criteria, 10, Core.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

In the first line the contours of the image were found. In the first for loop finds the center of each pip with cluster size 1 and store the center in a new Mat. After the for loop the center position of all pips are stored in the variable samples32final. 
With this variable the center of the dice can be found with kmeans.

Sorry for the bad english...